# Knockout JS: observableArray always remains empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

My goal is to produce a list of sortable elements that will be managed with knockout.  For some reason unkown to me, however, the observableArray that I create will always remain empty.  I feel as though I am missing something terribly obvious here...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//var initialData = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
//console.log(initialData);

var test = [{ Position: 1 },
            { Position: 2 },
            { Position: 3 },
            { Position: 4 },
            { Position: 5 }];

var viewModel = {};
    viewModel.Offers = ko.observableArray(test);

    viewModel.addOffer = function() {
        this.Offers.push({ Position : 5});
        console.log(this);
    };

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.body);

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable().disableSelection();
});
```

[JSFiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/wycleffsean/mCUhU/6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed to wrap template name in single quotation marks:

```
<ul id="sortable" 
    data-bind="template: {name: 'offerTemplate', foreach: Offers}">
```

Here is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCUhU/7/).